# Is convex hull of a finite set a linear subspace of linear hull?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

We have some convex and compact supset $G$ of Banach space $B$ and finitely many points ${x_1,...,x_N}$ . The question is : does the convex hull $C$ of ${x_1,...,x_N}$ a linear subspace of space $lin({x_1,...,x_N})$

I couldn't proove that 
for every $x, y \in C$ we have $x+y \in C$
Is this true?

Comment: In general, the convex hull is usually not a linear space.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is bounded, so is its convex hull. A non-zero linear space is not bounded.

Comment: non-zero, not non-empty.

Comment: of course :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

Attention please convex hull is closed under convex combination not arbitrary combination. $x+y$ is not convex combination of $x$ and $y$ so is not belong to convex hull of the set.